# How to get data from the user documents from firestore? (Flutter)

Tags: visual-studio, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'am new in flutter_programming.
 
I want to get the data from the `user.document`. I have already created a new collection if I sign up in my application. 
I use this command `snapshot.data.document[][]` (Streambuilder) for getting data from firestore.
But I have to declare the first array to access the document.
 
So I can't access automatically the user document.

Answer (score 0):

To get the data from Firestore you need to use the stream,

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> get data {
    return Firestore.instance.collection('yo').snapshots().map(_taskListFromSnapshot);
  }
}
```